# Formatar o valor do input usando [ngModel] e (ngModelChange) enquanto digita

Tags: angular, angular-material

Pesquisei no SO e SOPT para ver se tinha ocorrido com alguém a mesma coisa, mas acredito que não.
Tenho uma aplicação com um `input` para que um determinado valor seja digitado e formatado ao mesmo tempo, como segue:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Proposta" #valorPropostaInput [ngModel]="valorProposta" (ngModelChange)="valorProposta = FormatarValorExibicao(valorPropostaInput.value)">
```

No meu arquivo `.ts`, a função `FormatarValorExibicao` retorna o valor formatado para moeda brasileira:

```
valorProposta: string = '';

FormatarValorExibicao(valor)
{
    const v = ((valor.replace(/\D/g, '') / 100).toFixed(2) + '').split('.');

    const m = v[0].split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g);

    for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        m[i] = m[i].split('').reverse().join('') + '.';

    const r = m.reverse().join('');

    return [r.substring(0, r.lastIndexOf('.')), ',', v[1]].join('');
}
```

A função acima funciona corretamente. O problema está quando digito letras ao invés de números. Verifiquei que colocando `console.log` para o retorno do método, o valor é formatado corretamente, mas a **view** simplesmente não atualiza o valor com `[ngModel]`.

Para o `input` com valor de `12345`:

- O valor formatado pela função é `123,45` (correto);
- Caso eu coloque um caractere de texto (`123,45a` ou `123,45abcd`), o valor retornado pela função é o mesmo (`123,45` - correto), mas a view não é atualizada com o retorno. O valor exibido no `input` fica (`123,45a` ou `123,45abcd`);
- Se no `input` estiver `123,45a` ou `123,45abcd` e eu digitar um número qualquer (`6`), a view é atualizada e o comportamento esperado acontece (`1.234,56`) para ambos os casos.

Já tentei passar como parâmetro o `$event` para a função acima, mas sem sucesso:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Proposta" [ngModel]="valorProposta" (ngModelChange)="valorProposta = FormatarValorExibicao($event)">
```

Se eu modificar o `(ngModelChange)` para apenas chamar o método `FormatarValorExibicao` passando o `$event` ou a propriedade `value` do `input` e então dentro do método não retornar o valor, mas atribuir a variável `valorProposta` o esperado, dá na mesma. A view não é atualizada, i.e.:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Proposta" #valorPropostaInput [ngModel]="valorProposta" (ngModelChange)="FormatarValorExibicao(valorPropostaInput.value)">
```

```
<input matInput placeholder="Proposta" [ngModel]="valorProposta" (ngModelChange)="FormatarValorExibicao($event)">
```

E então:

```
FormatarValorExibicao(valor)
{
    const v = ((valor.replace(/\D/g, '') / 100).toFixed(2) + '').split('.');

    const m = v[0].split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g);

    for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        m[i] = m[i].split('').reverse().join('') + '.';

    const r = m.reverse().join('');

    this.valorProposta = [r.substring(0, r.lastIndexOf('.')), ',', v[1]].join('');
}
```

Acredito que o erro não esteja na `RegEx`, pois testei muitas vezes no site [Online JavaScript Editor](https://playcode.io/online-javascript-editor), mas posso estar errado. Tentei até adicionar a propriedade `name="algumaCoisa"` ao `input`, mas não fez diferença. A view não ser atualizada apenas quando digito letras é bem estranho, não sei como contornar isso ou se estou usando o `[ngModel]` e o `(ngModelChange)` de forma incorreta.

Obrigado.

Comment: me parece melhor usar alguma biblioteca de mascara ou algo assim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução seria trocar o evento e utilizar o [Two-way Data-binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax), veja a seção [Binding syntax: an overview](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview).

```
<input matInput placeholder="Proposta" [(ngModel)]="valorProposta" (keyup)="FormatarValorExibicao($event)" >
```

**Ficheiro .ts:**

```
//...
public valorProposta: any;

public FormatarValorExibicao($event): void {
   let valor = this.valorProposta;
   const v = ((valor.replace(/\D/g, '') / 100).toFixed(2) + '').split('.');
   const m = v[0].split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g);

   for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
       m[i] = m[i].split('').reverse().join('') + '.';

   const r = m.reverse().join('');
   this.valorProposta = [r.substring(0, r.lastIndexOf('.')), ',', v[1]].join('');
}
```

Entretanto há bibliotecas que já resolvem o problema, como por exemplo, [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask).

Comment: Obrigado, Filipe. Sua solução realmente funcionou. Só precisei inicializar a variável `valorPorposta` com `''`.